# Observable needs flatMap() on single()

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Every time I think I understand Observables, I don't quite understand Observables. So consider this code I use in my Angular 4 app:

```js
// this returns the url to our bitbucket server. the uriService returns
// an Observable<string>
return this.uriService.getBitBucketUrl(path)
  
  // I expect exactly one result, no more, no less, otherwise exception        
  .single() 

  // somehow I still need a flatMap here, to supply the url value into the nested observable
  .flatMap((url: string) => {
    
    // we now have the bitbucket url, use it to get json from it.
    return this.httpService.getJson(url)
      
     // map the result and flatten it to an array
     .flatMap((json: HttpResponse<any>): Array<any> => json.body.values)

     // map each value into a more managed model
     .map<any, BitbucketModel>((value: any) => {
        // create and return BitBucketModel here based on json
 })
});
```

I hope I explain the code well enough, so the essence of it is that I don't want to use 'subscribe' anywhere. because I use the async pipe I want observables all the way down. But when I use single() and then I have to flatMap it otherwise it gives me an error because I can't return Observable < Observable < BitBucketModel > >.

**EDIT**
I'm sorry if I didn't make it clear enough what I was asking. My scenario is that I basically need a config setting where my actual http request is based on. So I must retrieve that setting and based on that settings do that actual http request.

Comment: I didnt get two things : 1) Why use single 2) what are you asking exactly

Comment: @Skeptor, Single(), according to the docs, expects a single result from and obs, and that's exactly what I want. If it's not a single value it throws an exception. If you have additional insight, please let me know. Further; I'm sorry my question wasn't completely clear. I'll update it.

Comment: No problem, are you getting any error . Did I answer your question

Comment: @Skeptor you definitely clarified map vs flatMap. I'm still unsure as to why the output of a single() requires flattening because it can only emit a single result.

Comment: But its still a stream right .  The core concept of rx is "everything is a stream". Even if its a single item, its considered as a stream. This makes it easy to chain and reuse. It's a paradigm shift , you just need to get the 'aha' moment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are asking why `flatMap` . Let me try to explain.

> `map` converts input to output synchronously . So it takes each item transforms it to something else replaces old item with new one. This process is synchronous.

`flatMap` also does replace but instead does it asynchronously .

> `flatMap` takes an item, converts it to an Observable and output of the new Observable steam is put in place of original item.

So `flatMap` can be used in these two instance ( might be more applications) :

1. if output is asynchronous  ( ex. url to http call response )
2. if output is Observable  ( ex. Array to independent elements )

ex:

```
...'string1'... 'string2'... => 
 ...Output(Observable created from string1)...
 ...Output(Observable created from string2)...
```

In your case :

input : string ( url )

output : json from asynchronous http call .

So, you have to use `flatMap` . Its not related to `single()`

### Another point:

In your example  :

```
.flatMap((json: HttpResponse<any>): Array<any> => json.body.values)
```

this is a synchronous transformation . You are taking an object and synchronously returning another object . So it need not be a flatMap . You can just say

```
.map((json: HttpResponse<any>): Array<any> => json.body.values)
```

In fact your code should give an error as `flatMap` expects an `Observable` as return type but you are returning an object.